# Include dialog from another file via backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, jsf-2.2

I have a Primefaces project in which I am trying to replicate the behavior of a desktop application. Because of the nature of the desktop application, there are quite a few popup dialogs, which cause the processing of the page to become very slow (initial page load: 10-20 seconds, AJAX requests: 6-10 seconds).

I have separate files for all the dialogs already, and I want to use the backing bean to pop them up as dialogs without having to use `<ui:include>` in my main files. Is there a way to do this?

e.g.:

```
<p:commandButton id="showSearchDialog"
                 action="#{managedBean.showSearchDialog()}"/>
<p:dialog widgetVar="searchDialog">
</p:dialog>
```

```
public class ManagedBean {
  public void showSearchDialog() {
    //Some sort of function that knows to process the contents of searchDialog.xhtml
    //  and insert it into the relevant <p:dialog>

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('searchDialog').show()");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to reduce the size of the page, I'd approach it with conditional rendering of the dialog itself as determined by a backing bean property which would be set by the command action:

```
<p:commandButton id="showSearchDialog"
                 action="#{managedBean.showSearchDialog()}"
                 update="dialogs"
                 oncomplete="PF('searchDialog').show()" />
<h:panelGroup id="dialogs" layout="block">
 <p:dialog widgetVar="searchDialog" rendered="#{managedBean.currentDialog eq 'search'}">
  <ui:include src="searchDialog.xhtml" />
 </p:dialog>
</h:panelGroup>
```

```
public class ManagedBean {
  private String currentDialog;
  public String getCurrentDialog() { return currentDialog; }
  public void showSearchDialog() { currentDialog = "search"; }
}
```

Then you could conditionally render all of your dialogs within the 'dialogs' block and use ajax to refresh the rendered content dynamically.

---

Another option to consider is using the PrimeFaces Dialog Framework, which allows you to dynamically render an external page at runtime.

Comment: The only problem with this approach (as I discovered when I tried it) is that it still has to query the entire JSF tree in order to determine whether or not each dialog is rendered, which still takes time. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that since I already have all the dialogs defined in separate `xhtml` files. +1 for the suggestion though (and also partially to get your response above the other one)

Comment: Did you see the suggested option to use the PF Dialog Framework?  It's exactly what you're looking for since you already have your dialogs in separate files.  Pretty cool stuff.

Comment: That's what I said I was hoping to avoid. I don't want to have to recompile the code every time I need to make a change to one of the options on a dialog.

Comment: Recompile?  The dialog framework simply allows you to dynamically load an xhtml file within a dialog thru a postback call to an actionlistener on the server side.  No code to recompile.  You can even pass the outcome as an argument to a single actionlistener to be even more flexible.  All dialog content can be contained within the xhtml file.  Have you tried this?

Comment: All the tutorials I saw had an options object that had to be passed to the function, which would require recompilation.

Comment: No, that's optional.  As a minimum, you just specify the outcome (ie name of the xhtml file).  Give it a shot.  It's cool.

Comment: Right, I guess I'll try that tomorrow then.

Comment: Okay, so I know it's been a while since I last posted an update on this but I finally got around to trying the dialog framework and right away I encountered a major issue: I can't chain from dialog to dialog using it. It seems to call the backend to close the first dialog, but then it never brings up the second one. Do you know of a way around this problem?